# Virtual ListView undesired checkbox behavior using ListView_HitTest checking for LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON flag with extended style LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using a virtual ListView control and I am trying to get the checkboxes working properly. In NM_CLICK, my code copies the click point from the NM_LISTVIEW struct to LVHITTESTINFO hitInfo.pt. I then pass hitInfo to ListView_HitTest and if hitInfo.flags & LVHT_ONITEMSTATICON -> ToggleCheckBox ...

My code worked fine (only checking/unchecking if the checkbox itself was clicked) until I added the extended style LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT to the ListView. Now, if I select a row (at any point on the item), it will toggle the checkbox.

Is there any way to make this work (only toggle if the checkbox is clicked) without removing the LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT extended style?

EDIT:

```
NMLISTVIEW* pNMLstView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)lParam;

LVHITTESTINFO hitInfo;
hitInfo.pt = pNMLstView->ptAction;

int item = ListView_HitTest( hwndLstView, &hitInfo );

if ( item > -1 ) {
  if ( (hitInfo.flags & LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON) != 0 ) {
    ToggleCheckBox( item, hwndLstView );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code mentioned in the first paragraph pls?

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you are using `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` or not. Can you clarify?

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes, I am using LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES

Comment: Try deciphering this page: http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-cvs/2009-May/055658.html. It seems to suggest that special handling is indeed needed for hittesting `LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT` and `LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT` is enabled, hit testing reports `LVHT_ONITEM`, which is a combination of `LVHT_ONITEMICON`, `LVHT_ONITEMLABEL`, and `LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON`.  You need to filter out that condition, eg:

```
if ( (hitInfo.flags & LVHT_ONITEM) != LVHT_ONITEM ) {
    if ( (hitInfo.flags & LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON) != 0 ) {
        ToggleCheckBox( item, hwndLstView );
    }
}
```